# How to create a derived class that takes a wstring and call a base class constructor that takes a string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, initialization

Some time ago, I found a clever trick on stackoverflow that showed a way to create a derived exception class from `runtime_error` that accepts a wstring as a constructor. The trick was to initialize the `runtime_error` base with a virtual method call. Here's what that looks like:

```
UnknownEx(const std::wstring& s) throw() : m_msg(s), std::runtime_error( what() ) {};
```

And `what()` does the conversion (I'm okay with the lossy conversion from wstring to string):

```
virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    // Convert the wstring data member to a char*.
    const wchar_t* wstr = m_msg.c_str();
    char *str = new char[wcslen(wstr)];
    size_t *charsChanged = 0;
    wcstombs_s(charsChanged, str, sizeof(str), wstr, _TRUNCATE);

    return str; 
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to utilize it:

```
throw UnknownEx(L"Test Exception");
```

The application fails in the midst of `what()` when trying to find the length of the data member `m_msg`. When debugging into `what()`, `m_msg` hasn't yet been set. It seems this function call in the initializer list trick isn't working.

Is there a way to get this "trick" to work properly, or is my entire approach misguided?

**My long term goal:** I would simply like to create a derived exception class that is able to be caught generically with `catch(exception& ex)`, but accepts a `wstring` in its constructor.

Comment: Worst case you can always convert from one to the other via `wcsrtombs()`. I posted code for that several times on SO. It's a separate question whether such an involved operation is acceptable in an exception constructor.

Comment: There is a memory leak in your code. You return heap-allocated `str` variable and no one calls `delete[]` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program crashes because `std::runtime_error(what())` is executed before `m_msg(s)`.  Base classes are initialized before member variables.

While your call to `what()` will in this case call your `UnknownEx` override, it's best not to call virtual functions from constructors, because the semantics are confusing.

If you are going to store your exception message in your own `m_msg` member variable, don't derive from `std::runtime_error`; there's no reason to store the string twice.  Consider deriving directly from `std::exception`.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear, `m_msg` is a wstring. If the "trick" worked, then I would have my own `m_msg` holding the true wstring, and `runtime_error` would hold the char* string. My code deals entirely with wstring, so having an exception class that only takes char* would make for a lot more conversion boilerplate everywehre. Is your answer implying there's no "good" way to accomplish what I'm setting out to do?

Comment: I recommend that you derive from `exception` and override `what()` to convert the wide string into a narrow string, similar to what you've already done.  (However, note that your `UnknownEx` class needs to own the string returned by `what()`.  It is responsible for deleting the allocated memory when it is destroyed.  I'd recommend using a `std::string` member variable to own the storage, and convert the `std::wstring` into the `std::string`.)

Comment: That's much more clear, thank you. That did the trick, I'm not sure why I was making that more complicated than it needed to be.